# .Net Core C# Execute method/class as a subprocess

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core, process

For reasons of memory isolation and stability I need to execute some methods/classes as sub-processes, not threads.
I found the following library that allows me to do just that: https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction.

However, I can't seem to find a way to get the process ID of the child process.

```
ExecFunction.Run(() => new NewSubProcessClass());
```

The code above will generate a new process and will even generate console output in a Linux Docker container. The problem is, that I have no process ID.

```
public static Process Start(Action action, Action<ExecFunctionOptions> configure = null);
```

The method I quoted above looked like it should do the trick, however, when I replace

```
ExecFunction.Run(() => new NewSubProcessClass());
```

with

```
Process process = ExecFunction.Start(() => new NewSubProcessClass());
```

I no longer get any console output.

**UPDATE 0:**

The suggestion from @bazzilic

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

is the solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? E.g., when you do `.Start(...`, do you do `process.WaitForExit();` after that?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `Action<ExecFunctionOptions> configure`? The constructor of `ExecFunctionOptions` expects an object of type `System.ProcessStartInfo`. Such an object has a property called `UseShellExecute`. As far as I can tell from the documentation, setting this property to `true` may do the trick. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_UseShellExecute

Comment: Thanks, process.WaitForExit(); did the trick.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a proper answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the source code for `Tmds.ExecFunction`, both methods `.Run(...)` ([here](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction/blob/fb2471f40cebea5b92eda59c63bbab88f295027b/src/Tmds.ExecFunction/ExecFunction.cs#L43)) and `.Start(...)` ([here](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction/blob/fb2471f40cebea5b92eda59c63bbab88f295027b/src/Tmds.ExecFunction/ExecFunction.cs#L19)) under the hood call the same private method `.Start(...)` (source [here](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction/blob/fb2471f40cebea5b92eda59c63bbab88f295027b/src/Tmds.ExecFunction/ExecFunction.cs#L91)). The two differences are:

1. the public `.Start(...)` method returns the `process` object from the tuple returned by the private `.Start(...)` method whereas `.Run(...)` does not;
2. the `.Run(...)` method also supplies `waitForExit: true` in the parameters.

In the code of the private `.Start(...)` method, there is [this portion](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction/blob/fb2471f40cebea5b92eda59c63bbab88f295027b/src/Tmds.ExecFunction/ExecFunction.cs#L125):

```cs
if (waitForExit)
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Other than that, the two public methods are identical. The difference in your code behavior is most likely due to not waiting for the child process to finish in your parent process. Try this:

```cs
Process process = ExecFunction.Start(() => new NewSubProcessClass());
process.WaitForExit();
```

PS: Keep in mind that `Process` is `IDisposable`, so might be better to do

```cs
using ( Process process = ExecFunction.Start(() => new NewSubProcessClass()) ) {
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```